# Home tab pagination bug

Tags: bug, new-nav, homepage, pagination

The first time I noticed this bug was around March 2016, but it didn't really bother me enough for me to add an entry here, and I assumed someone else had probably reported it and it would get fixed in the following weeks.
Now, almost a year later and I stumble upon the same bug, so here it is:

## Description

When I go to the homepage, Stack Overflow remembers my `items per page` preference, but if I change the page, the `items per page` preference resets to 15.

I think it's also worth pointing out that if in a window you set an `items per page` number, you can change pages all you want, and it works as expected. The problem seems to happen when the preference is retrieved from wherever it's retrieved.

[image: Pagination]

Comment: I think they should use a single cookie to store you preference

Comment: Did I somehow imply they're not using a single cookie?, or do you know there is more than one cookie being used?